# How to use Bootstrap tabs with Block Content in Django

Tags: django, bootstrap-4

I cannot figure out how to use Boostrap Tabs, when block content is needed and I am unable to make sue of the href in tab li a item.  See below for any ideas.  thanks for any help.

When you click on the below, it changes the tabs as expected, however, how do you incorporate django views?  for example when the email tab is clicked, show the tab view for {% url 'account_email' %} in the content pane?

```
<div class="container mt-5">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-lg-7">
                            <nav>
                                <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                                  <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-email-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-email" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-email" aria-selected="true">E-mail</a>
                                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-password-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-password" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-password" aria-selected="false">Password</a>
                                  <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-connect-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-connect" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-connect" aria-selected="false">Connect</a>
                                </div>
                              </nav>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <div class="container mt-5 text-center mx-auto">
                                <div class="card p-5">
                                    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-email" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-email-tab">
                                            {% block email_content %}{% endblock %}
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-password" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-password-tab">
                                            {% block password_content %}{% endblock %}
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-connect" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-connect-tab">
                                            {% block connect_content %}{% endblock %}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up completing the solution with a much more simple approach using request.path to set the appropriate tag active, then just use the tab href to directly reference the view for that tab.

```
                <div class="container mt-5">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-lg-7">
                            <nav>
                                <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab">
                                  <a class="nav-item nav-link {% if 'accounts/email' in request.path %}active{% endif %}" id="nav-email-tab" href="{% url 'account_email' %}" aria-selected="true">E-mail</a>
                                  <a class="nav-item nav-link {% if 'accounts/password/change' in request.path %}active{% endif %}" id="nav-password-tab" href="{% url 'account_change_password' %}" aria-selected="false">Password</a>
                                  <a class="nav-item nav-link {% if 'accounts/social/connections' in request.path %}active{% endif %}" id="nav-connect-tab" href="{% url 'socialaccount_connections' %}" aria-selected="false">Connect</a>
                                </div>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <div class="container mt-5 text-center mx-auto">
                                <div class="card p-5">
                                    {% block base_content %}
                                    {% endblock %}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this case, you have 2 options:

1. Load the whole page of {% url 'account_email' %} into a iframe, and display that iframe in the mentioned tab
2. put the template of {% url 'account_email' %} into an independent HTML file that can be included into the html section of this tab, using {% include "path to the html file" %}, and of course this HTMl template will use the same context as the current view, meaning you will have to send all the context data from the view of {% url 'account_email' %} into this view.

Remember that Django template render everything FROM THE SERVER SIDE, so everything end-user sees are pre-rendered before. Unless you use Ajax here.